# Is it possible to a establish a TCP/IP connection over bluetooth?

Tags: android, encryption, bluetooth

Well, the following situation: Devices need to communicate offline. The only option is Bluetooth. Here, the issue is that Bluetooth's encryption is insecure and broken. See KNOB attack.

Therefore, I'm looking for a way to securely exchange data between two bluetooth devices (e.g.,Android and iOS). My current guess is to establish a TCP/IP connection to make use of typical SSL/TLS libraries with all its other advantages (certificate check etc.) and disable bluetooth's encryption for performance increase.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket
Unfortunately, it appears that this idea is already not supported by Android. They do offer some sort of BluetoothSocket, but that is not a TCP/IP connection afaik. Does anyone know a way to enable a TCP/IP connection between two bluetooth devices? Any other idea to secure that broken bluetooth connection?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is yes. Nevertheless, there is no usable API on Android (before Android 9 via reflections maybe) and it still has the hide annotation on Android 11 in its source code, besides the requirement of a special permission to be used by system apps only.

The only option is to enable Bluetooth tethering via system settings (if available). Next devices connecting over Bluetooth will get an IP address, while the smartphone acts as the router. The access of services on the smartphone is permitted.